# React + Vite troubles to redirect to new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have troubles to redirect to a new page. Button is redirecting only from homepage and also when I click, it  is showing other pages below. I want to render only one page after clicking. Thank you very much for any help.

```html
import { Stars } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link, Navigate, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Kuryr from "./Kuryr";
import { About, Contact, Experience, Feedbacks, Hero, Navbar, Tech,  StarsCanvas, OurTeam   } from "./components";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className='relative z-0 bg-primary'>
        <div className='bg-hero-pattern bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-center'>
          <Navbar />
          
          <Routes>
         
          <Route path="/Kuryr" exact element={<Kuryr />} />
      </Routes>
      
      
          <Hero />
        </div>
        <About />
        <Experience />
        <Tech />
        
        <OurTeam />
        <div className='relative z-0'>
          <Contact />
          
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you provide the code snippet to understand better?

Comment: Hello Milan, i did right now.

Comment: Alright, I have provided the right ans! if you want you can also check out the docs as well.